# How to limit Docker total resources?

Tags: rhel, systemd, docker

I'm trying to limit the total resources accessible from docker (for example only 90% of the RAM and 1500% of the CPU). I cannot use CPU and RAM limit when I'm launching my containers, that's why I need to limit the total resources available for docker containers.

I have around 20 containers which can consume the maximum CPU and memory but not at the same time, so I cannot set the CPU and RAM limit, that's why I need to limit the total resource used by docker

First of all I've created a slice: I tried the instruction above, but impossible to limit both the RAM and the CPU usage

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker_limit.slice
[Unit]
Description=Slice that limits docker resources
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=700%
#Memory Management
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=20G
MemoryMax=25G
MemoryMaxSwap=10G
```

And my daemon.json

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : [ "url1", "url2"],
  "cgroup-parent": "docker_limit.slice"
}
```

But when I try from a container:

```
stress --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1
```

I can see from docker stats it's using 111Go of Ram (full capacity of my server)

```
stress --cpu 16
```

I can see from docker stats it's using near 1600 % (full capacity of my server)

I think I've missed something but I don't know what

Answer (score 19):

For other person who will need a complete answer to this question, I'm doing a full recap:

First of all I've created a slice called docker_limit:

1. Create a file to `/etc/systemd/system/docker_limit.slice`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Slice that limits docker resources
   Before=slices.target

   [Slice]
   CPUAccounting=true
   CPUQuota=700%
   #Memory Management
   MemoryAccounting=true
   MemoryLimit=25G
   ```
2. Start unit: `systemctl start docker_limit.slice`
3. Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

   ```
   {
     "cgroup-parent": "docker_limit.slice"
   }
   ```
4. Restart Docker daemon: `systemctl restart docker`

In order to verify all works as expected: `systemd-cgtop`, you should see processes listed under `docker_limit.slice`. e.g.:
[image]

credit to @rwos

Comment: @volky.eth Thank you for your edit suggestion. However, please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/377345) - copy-and-paste with block code formatting instead. In your case, the intended highlighting can probably omittes since the output is rather easy to parse visually.

Comment: Note that MemoryLimit is an option for controlling the Legacy Control Group Hierarchy (Control Groups version 1) and is now fully deprecated according to documentation at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html. Use MemoryHigh/MemoryMax instead

Answer (score 7):

Prefix the `cgroup_parent` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with a `/`, so the cgroup name is absolute. Otherwise, docker will put the containers into a sub-cgroup of the daemon's cgroup:

```
{
    "cgroup-parent": "/docker_limit.slice"
}
```

Without the `/`, depending on your system, the containers might end up in `/system.slice/containerd.service/docker_limit.slice` or similar.

`systemd-cgtop` or `systemd-cgls` can be used to check where things ended up running.

Comment: Is it possible to specify % based metric for the RAM, instead of an absolute value. I'd like to set the daemon to use no more than 80% of the machine it is running on, and I have various machines - I don't want to create different file for different machines.

Comment: @LIvanov not that I know of, no - see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html for what's possible to set (depends on the systemd/kernel version a bit).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore as reported by @Benjamin and at least in docker 24

Answer (score 2):

I have a VM with 1 CPU and 2GB RAM (swap disabled).
Therefore I created the slice with next parameters:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker_limit.slice
[Unit]
Description=Slice that limits docker resources
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=90%
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=1G
MemoryMax=1.2G
```

And I made literally the same things as you, except native cgroupdriver in daemon:

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
    "cgroup-parent": "docker_limit.slice"
}
```

Then I ran docker container with:

```
docker run --name stress-test -d ubuntu:18.04 sleep 10000
```

And opened my VM in 2 windows. In the 1st window, I ran `stress`. In the 2nd window, I ran the `docker stats command`. CPU was around 90%+-(htop confirm this and I saw some spikes to up to 91%) and when RAM was close to 1.2G, then this process exited with the message:

```
# stress --cpu 1 --vm 1 --vm-bytes 1300M
stress: info: [334] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: FAIL: [334] (415) <-- worker 336 got signal 9
stress: WARN: [334] (417) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [334] (451) failed run completed in 4s
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposal made above by rwos (I unfortunately can't directly comment on the post), does not work for me.

> Prefix the cgroup_parent in /etc/docker/daemon.json with a /, so the
> cgroup name is absolute.

I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: invalid slice name: /docker_limit.slice: unknown

Without the "/" prefix, my docker containers start. With it, they do not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/449726)